# MongoDB, buscar en múltiples campos para múltiples valores

Tags: mongodb

No estoy acostumbrado a hacer consultas complejas en mongoDB y hay una que no sé como orientar. Tengo documentos del estilo:

```
{
    title: "Don Quijote de la Mancha",
    author: "Miguel de Cervantes",
    ...
}
```

Si quisiera buscar por 'title' que contenga un conjunto de valores dados podría hacer:

```
db.collection.find( { $and: [{titulo: /miguel/i}, {titulo: /cervantes/i}] } );
```

Pero lo que quiero hacer es que dado un conjunto de valores, me busque por el campo 'title' y 'author' los documentos que tengan esos valores entre ambos campos. Es decir, la anterior consulta con los valores [miguel, cervantes] me devolvería el documento que le he puesto de ejemplo, pero si paso los valores [miguel, quijote] no lo devolveria porque quijote no está en el campo 'title', pero quiero una consulta que fuera capaz de devolver los documentos que tengas esos valores sin importar en el campo en el que estén.

EDITADO

Una solución más cercana sería crear un índice

```
db.collection.createIndex({ author: "text", title: "text" });
```

Y luego realizar la consulta:

```
db.collection.find({ $text : { $search: 'Miguel Quijote', $caseSensitive:false } });
```

En este caso me devolvería los documentos que tengan en algunos de los campos indexados (author o title) el valor 'Miguel' o 'Quijote'. Trataría cada palabra como una búsqueda OR. También ha la opción de que haga la búsqueda exacta de frase, pero yo lo que necesito es que lo trate como una búsqueda AND. Quiero que TODAS las palabras de la búsqueda aparezcan en los documentos devueltos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta no se entiende bien. Pero si tuvieras una colección `prueba` con los documentos

```
{ "title" : "Don Quijote de la Mancha", "author" : "Miguel de Cervantes" }
{ "title" : "FuenteOvejuna", "author" : "Lope de Vega" }
{ "title" : "Niebla", "author" : "Miguel de Unamuno" }
{ "title" : "Miguel y el Dragón", "author": "Elizabeth Heck"}
```

La consulta

```
db.prueba.find({ $or: [{author:/miguel/i}, {title: /miguel/i}] });
```

Te devolvería

```
{ "title" : "Don Quijote de la Mancha", "author" : "Miguel de Cervantes" }
{ "title" : "Niebla", "author" : "Miguel de Unamuno" }
{ "title" : "Miguel y el Dragón", "author": "Elizabeth Heck"}
```

Si no conoces los campos de cada documento no puedes hacer una consulta de ese tipo, de manera que al insertar un documento como:

```
{ "nombre" : "san miguel" }
```

No te serviría buscar por los campos "title" o "author". **Peeero...** lo que puedes hacer es crear un índice de texto sobre la colección indexando todos los campos

```
db.prueba.createIndex({ "$**": "text" });
```

Y luego buscar usando el operador `$text` en combinación con `$search`. Este operador no acepta expresiones regulares como parámetro (sólo strings), pero puedes decirle que sea case-insensitive:

```
db.prueba.find({ $text : { $search: 'Miguel', $caseSensitive:false } });
```

Y buscará en todos los campos indexados (en este caso, todos los campos de la colección) por el match del texto parcial "Miguel", por lo que devolverá:

```
{ "title" : "Don Quijote de la Mancha", "author" : "Miguel de Cervantes" }
{ "title" : "Niebla", "author" : "Miguel de Unamuno" }
{ "title" : "Miguel y el Dragón", "author": "Elizabeth Heck"}
{ "nombre": "san miguel"}
```

PS: `$search` también permite ignorar acentos y diacríticos en general poniéndole `$diacriticSensitive : false`

**EDIT en base al comentario**:

Supongamos que insertas un nuevo registro:

```
{ "apodo" : "miguelito", "direccion":"Avenida el Quijote 455" }
```

Ese registro contiene "Miguel" y "Quijote" y tú quieres todos los registros que contengan ambas palabras. Si haces:

```
db.prueba.find({ $text : { $search: 'Miguel Quijote'} });
```

Te traerá todos los registros que contengan "Miguel" **O** "Quijote" (y **no es lo que se quiere**).

Puedes pedir una coincidencia exacta haciendo:

```
db.prueba.find({ $text : { $search: '"Miguel Quijote"'} });
```

Pero ningún documento tiene ese texto exacto, porque Miguel y Quijote están en campos distintos. (por tanto, **tampoco sirve**)

¿Cómo se hace entonces? Se puede pedir **más de una coincidencia exacta**:

```
db.prueba.find({ $text : { $search: '"Miguel" "Quijote"' } });
```

Y eso devuelve:

```
{ "title" : "Don Quijote de la Mancha", "author" : "Miguel de Cervantes" },
{ "apodo" : "miguelito", "direccion":"Avenida el Quijote 455" }
```

Los únicos dos registros que contienen tanto "Miguel" como "Quijote"

Comment: Tu solución es casi perfecta a mis necesidades. El caso es que yo no sólo voy a buscar un valor, y search solo admite un string. Necesito que los documento que devuelva tengan (entre todos los campos deseados) todos los valores de la consulta.

Comment: Mira la edición a la respuesta. Aprovecho de mencionar que no siempre es buena idea *refinar* la pregunta pegando el segmento de una solución, porque a ojos de un visitante X que llegue a esta página, la primera parte de mi respuesta deja de tener sentido y sólo terminará más confundido que al principio